# apex:inputCheckBox selected attribute is not working

Tags: visualforce, controller

i write a small snippet related to apex:inputCheckBox

```
<apex:inputCheckbox onclick="callRemoteFunction(this,{!num})" selected="{!isItemSelected}"/>
```

i am facing error

```
 Unknown function isItemSelected. Check spelling
```

in my custom controller there is a function named isItemSelected here is definition

```
public Boolean isItemSelected(){
    System.debug('---coming here---');
    return false;
    }
```

can anyone please explain why i am facing this issue when there is a corresponding function in controller ??

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your method to:

```
public Boolean getIsItemSelected(){
    System.debug('---coming here---');
    return false;
}
```

Methods that can be accessed in Visualforce need to be [defined as getters](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm):

> One of the primary tasks for a Visualforce controller class is to give
>   developers a way of displaying database and other computed values in
>   page markup. Methods that enable this type of functionality are called
>   getter methods, and are typically named getIdentifier, where
>   Identifier is the name for the records or primitive values returned by
>   the method.

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce actually binds to properties normally exposed like this:

```
public Boolean isItemSelected { get; set; }
```

but can also bind to methods (with names prefixed with get or set) but for where read and write access is needed **as it is in this case** that ends up being quite verbose:

```
private Boolean isItemSelected;
public Boolean getIsItemSelected() {
    return isItemSelected;
}
public void setIsItemSelected(Boolean value) {
    isItemSelected = value;
}
```

Its worth getting used to using the first form. See [Apex Properties](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_properties.htm) for more information.